# PCB Manufacturer defects, what process/protocol to used?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

During the manufacturing of 10,000 units of circuits, there are 10% defects in total.

As an electronics test engineer, what can I do to improve this situation?

- Edit: Referring to "PCB fabrication defects"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Thank you. I had edited this question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the suspected failure cause or at least the failure mode? Try and do a [Pareto chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_chart)  and tackle the top 3 failure modes/causes that account for most of the defects. Depending on what they are, the solution could be through design changes, better handling or working practices (ESD), better training of operators, better packaging, etc...

Comment: Ishikawa (Fishbone) diagram

Comment: Thank you both, it is very useful

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it is adequate.